# Clear all sessions on application start

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-variables

I noticed that when I restart my ASP.Net application, logged users' credentials are remembered and they may find themserves automatically logged in.
This behaviour is unwanted as long as the users' session variables, set at login time, are not carried along.
So, how can I "forget" all sessions on the application start?

I see that I can't use `Session.Abandon()` in the `Application_Start` event.

Comment: Do you use SQL server to store the sessions ?

Comment: Or the ASP.NET State Service?

Comment: How is your session state configured? Please paste this part of your web.config here.

Comment: which session mode are you using ?

Comment: Are you trying this with Visual studio debugger, if that is the case VS will not stop the ASP.net development server sometimes, this might be the issue, just check that in your notification area and stop it

Answer (score 1):

After restarting Session exists ? How it is possible? Probably you are using Session state server or Sql server. You can not use Session.Abandon() in the Application_Start event because when application starts, at that time, there is no session exists. Call Session.Clear() or Session.Abandon() method in the Application_End event so when application restarts it must clear all the session..

Answer (score 1):

Use this code when a new session is started i.e. add it in Global.asax

```
    #region remove all cookies

    string[] myCookies = Request.Cookies.AllKeys;
    foreach (string cookie in myCookies)
    {
        Response.Cookies[cookie].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    }

    #endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

you must clear you cookies like this :

```
foreach (string key in Request.Cookies.AllKeys)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(key);
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

**EDTI :**
    doing this all of your cookies will be expired.and the browser will attempt to delete all you'r cookies.and this will result in not remembering login state of your users.

hope this helps.

Comment: this is part of your sentence "forget all sessions".what i have inferred from this sentence is that you want to "not remember" any user.is it true?or something is wrong with my understanding?

Comment: This is forget only the session of the current user - the one that runs that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Forms Authentication, it's expected behaviour: the user still has a valid FormsAuthentication cookie even if your application has restarted.

If you really want to log them out, you just need to call `FormsAuthentication.SignOut`.

But I'd question the need to do this - why force the user to enter his credentials again?  If you've lost state that was stored in Session, you may need to redirect to a Home page or something, but no need to make the user log in again.